# Why I'm not able to run the working PHP website from remote linux server on my local linux machine?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file-permissions, http-status-code-403

I've on working website installed on Remote Linux Server.

All the files of a website are present inside a directory `'/var/www/'` on that remote linux server.

I connected to that remote server using **Filezilla** and downloaded all the file that are present in `'/var/www/'`

I'm also using Ubuntu Linux, Apache web server on my local machine.

I put all the downloaded files into the folder called `'new_website'` which is present at location `'/var/www/new_website'`

After that I hit the URL 'http://localhost/new_website' in a browser and I got following error message.

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /new_website on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

Then I googled for the solution and come to know that i've to give 755 permission to the file '.htaccess' which is present into a folder `'/var/www/new_website'`. Even after doing that I got the same error. Can someone please let me know what could be the solution for this issue. For your reference I'm putting below the code of file `'/var/www/new_website/.htaccess'`

Note : For security concerns I've used the duplicate URL of my working website in following code of .htaccess as 'www.mywebsite.com'

```
######################################
## [PHPFOX_HEADER]
##
## @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
## @author          Raymond Benc
## @package         PhpFox
## @version         $Id: htaccess.txt 5866 2013-05-10 09:06:38Z Raymond_Benc $
######################################

# Options -Indexes
# Options -Multiviews

# Header unset Pragma
# FileETag None
# Header unset ETag

# URL Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #
    #  Full path to your site
    #
    RewriteBase /

    # Rename Photo Names
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)_([0-9]*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3_$5.$6
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3.$5 

    # 301 redirect if missing www.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.% {HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # 301 redirect if missing trailing slash
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    #
    #  Rules
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?do=/$1

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Image Access Protection
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/(.*)\.(.*)$ static/image.php?file=$1&ext=$2
</IfModule>

# Modify Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive ON

    # Cache files
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>

    # Cache JavaScript & CSS
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Compress JavaScript & CSS
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

order allow,deny
deny from 77.99.11.22
allow from all
```

Let me know if you need any further information from me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Change your folder permissions. `chmod 777`

Comment: @Thamizhan:Do you mean the folder permission of the folder '/var/www/new_website' recursively and no need to make any change to the code of file '/var/www/new_website/.htaccess'?

Comment: no need to edit `.htaccess`, that's enough

Comment: I would not recommend using `sudo chmod 777 . -R`  Not even `chmod 777` on a production server, it will leave your files and directories wide open for everyone. Instead find out what group / users that need access and set the permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the permission of the files/folders in that director.

In terminal, go to that directory and type in,

```
sudo chmod 777 . -R
```

to change the permission of all the files recursively

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify server settings for new server (settings such as DB, user, host, etc) here : **//yournewserver/include/setting/server.sett.php**  , otherwise will not work. To debug, enable or create the file **//yournewserver/include/setting/dev.sett.php** ... after you solve the problem, you just rename it to whatever, for later use. It automatically detects it and runs the debug for you once you run the program. The .htaccess file you can modify after you setup the new server parameters. The first thing you need to do is connect to the database and make sure the **//yournewserver/file** folder is totally writable chmode 777 recursively, after the upgrade or migration, you will need to chmod to whatever the admin panel will tell you if you need to do anything else like deleting the install folder or any other chmod issues. My server tells me what to do after intallation : ***"Main file folder is writable (file/). This is a security risk and this folder should not have any "write" permission."*** but you do that after everything works right.

Once you enable or create that debug file, errors will display once you run PHPFOX from localhost or the IP in your local server. If you dont have that file, you can create a new one. This is the code for PHPFOX V3.8 ... you can create it and put it in that folder. That debug file may vary from versions. Check the proper one for your version, but you can give it a try. Good luck.

```
<?php 
    // Log error messages to XML flat file within the cache folder 
    define('PHPFOX_LOG_ERROR', true); 

    // Enable debug 
    define('PHPFOX_DEBUG', true); 

    // Debug level 
    define('PHPFOX_DEBUG_LEVEL', 3); 

    // Force browsers to re-cache static files on each page refresh 
    define('PHPFOX_NO_CSS_CACHE', true); 
    define('PHPFOX_DEBUG_EXIT', true); 
    define('PHPFOX_NO_TEMPLATE_CACHE', true); 
?>
```